# how to grab 2nd field of first line of a pipe delimited text file stored in hfds through shell script

Tags: unix, awk, sed, hdfs

I am new to Unix commands.
I have a pipe delimited test file in hdfs. I want to grab second field of the first line from the file through shell script and store it in variable.
To read the first line I used the following command but its showing error of `-head unknown command`

```
line=$(hadoop fs -head -n 1 $new_file)
```

I know for grabbing second field of a line we can use

```
y=$(echo $x | awk '{print $2}')

echo $y
```

where y will be the first line of the file

Comment: Pooja, you need not to use `head` then `awk`, `awk` could take care of it by itself.

Answer (score 0):

Second field of first line only then following will help you. So I am using `exit` so that only first line will be read and it shouldn't read all the lines of Input_file.

```
variable=$(awk -F"|" 'FNR==1{print $2;exit}' Input_file)
```

***Explanation of above code:***

`variable=$(..)`: Creating a variable named variable and it has the command to get the 2nd field of 1st line and it will store its value in it.

`awk`'s explanation here:

`-F"|"`: Setting field separator for lines.

`FNR==1`:  Checking if line is first line.

`print $2`: Printing the 2nd field of first line.

`exit`: exit will not read further file and will save our time.

Comment: @pooja, what do you mean by `HDFS` file? Kindly elaborate it?

Comment: HDFS is hadoop distributed file system..My text file is present in hadoop environment I think similar command as yours   starting with hadoop -fs  should work

Comment: @pooja, not sure, you could give it a try and report back then.

Answer (score 0):

this should do...

```
$ var="$(awk -F'|' '{print $2; exit}' file)"
```

it will extract the second field from the first line.